# PHP will not return multiple returns

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to render out multiple returns, what is the best way of rendering both returns.

One of them returns which is the deleteable collect, the updatable doesn't return.

```
public function getPosts()
{

    $posts = Post::with('user')->get();
    $response = new Response(json_encode($posts));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 
    return response()->json(Post::with('user')->get()->map(function(Post $post){ 
        return collect($post->toArray())->put('deletable', auth()->user()->can('delete', $post)); 
        return collect($post->toArray())->put('update', auth()->user()->can('update', $post));
    })); 
}
```

**updated**, posts don't appear doing the following:

```
public function getPosts()
{
    $posts = collect(Post::with('user')->get());
    $response = new Response(json_encode($posts));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 

    $data = $posts->map(function(Post $post)
    { 
        $post->toArray()->put('deletable', auth()->user()->can('delete', $post)); 
        $post->toArray()->put('update', auth()->user()->can('update', $post));

        return $post;
    });

    return response()->json($data); 
}
```

Comment: You can't return more than once per function call. The function exits as soon as you return. The first return will run, the function will exit, and the second will never been seen. A good IDE would have told you that the second return is dead code.

Comment: i use sublime text, what will be the best way to tackle this ?

Comment: For that reason conditional control structures like `if` is found.

Comment: @SaidbakR still not understanding

Comment: Return an array of your objects.  Then deconstruct it as required in your calling code.

Comment: if you write return twice, the code will stop at the first return. If you write return 10 times, the code execution still stops at the first.

Comment: i understand the problem, but i don't know a solution to it, i tried putting it in array but it didnt work.

Comment: In other words, logically, you can not give me two answers in the same exact time. Your program is like you. Use `if` to control which return that the function have to use.

Comment: @BARNOWL If you need to return multiple values, you need to stick everything in a structure like an array, then return that structure. An array will work. If you can't get it to work, you need to give specific information so we have a hope of helping you.

Comment: i updated the code, check to see if im in the ballpark

Comment: @BARNOWL And if you want a good IDE for PHP, look at PHPStorm. Sublime is more of a fancy text editor than an IDE afaik.

Comment: @Carcigenicate am i somewhat in the ballpark now ?

Comment: @Carcigenicate it didn't work, it breaks my code.

Comment: 1- You may need to use `else` beside `if` for the other condition. 2- `$troll` is undefined, you may have to define it in somewhere or pass it to the callback of `map`

Comment: @SaidbakR im still not understanding. i want to learn but im slow. how would i use an array to return this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something along the lines of :

```
public function getPosts()
{
    $posts = Post::with('user')->get();
    $response = new Response(json_encode($posts));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 

    $data = $posts->map(function(Post $post)
    { 
        $post->toArray())->put('deletable', auth()->user()->can('delete', $post); 
        $post->toArray())->put('update', auth()->user()->can('update', $post);

        return $post;
    });

    return response()->json($data); 
}
```

Whats going on here:

1. Use the $posts variable in the array map instead of making the call again.
2. Do the actions to each $post in the array map.
3. Return the $post to the array of $data.
4. Return the $data.

Here are the docs on array maps and return.

You CANNOT return more than once.

Read these:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-map

http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

Update:

Try this:

```
public function getPosts()
{
    $posts = Post::with('user')->get();
    $response = new Response(json_encode($posts));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 


    $data = $posts->map(function(Post $post)
    { 
        $user = auth()->user();

        if($user->can('delete', $post)) {
            $post['deletable'] = true;
        }

        if($user->can('update', $post)) {
            $post['update'] = true;
        }
        return $post;
    })

    return response()->json($data); 
}
```

Comment: this looks sort of "hacky", is there a way i can pass the two collect returns into an array, to make it look more php 7 appropriate. I understand whats going on being that you explained it, but the format is quite "hacky"

Comment: your a life saver, been looking for the that sneaky collections documentation thanks

Comment: tried your code worked out the syntax errors now my posts don't appear.

Comment: yeah, posts don't appear ill edit the thread to show you what i got.

Comment: So when you dump the $posts variable before changing it are there posts? `dd($posts)` or `return $posts` before declaring the `$data` variable to test it.

Comment: i got this on my network script:

`Call to a member function put() on array"` on line 45

Comment: If there are posts then the algorithms within the array map will need to worked on

Comment: did you check the updated code, i made some changes to it, let me know if the syntax is right, posts dont show

Comment: You made me a happy owl , thank you :) hoo hooo hoot